# How to cause a component to re render in react when using a hook which holds some state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to re render a component when a prop changes. My component uses a custom hook which holds the state of a form. In useEffect whenever the prop called refresh changes I want to re render the page. I have tried countless solutions including making a forceUpdate function and calling it when the prop changes, I tried changing state so that the component should re render, but the information in my for does not clear. Below is my code.

Component:

```
const CustomerInformationForm = (props) => {
  const [triggerRefresh, setTriggerRefresh] = useState();
  const initialState = {
    name: {
      value: "",
      isValid: false,
    },
    phone: {
      value: "",
      isValid: false,
    },
    address: {
      value: "",
      isValid: true,
    },
  };

  const initialValidity = false;

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("customerinfo refreshing");
    setTriggerRefresh(props.refresh);
  }, [props.refresh]);

  let [formState, inputHandler] = useForm(
    initialState,
    initialValidity
  );
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Customer Information</h3>
      <form className="customer-information_form">
        <Input
          id="name"
          label="Name"
          type="text"
          element="input"
          validators={[VALIDATOR_REQUIRE()]}
          errorText="Please enter a valid name."
          onInput={inputHandler}
          onChange={props.customerInfo(formState)}
        />
        <Input
          type="text"
          element="input"
          id="phone"
          label="Phone"
          validators={[VALIDATOR_MINLENGTH(8)]}
          errorText="Please enter a valid phone number."
          onInput={inputHandler}
          onChange={props.customerInfo(formState)}
        />
        <Input
          type="text"
          element="input"
          id="address"
          label="Address"
          validators={[]}
          onInput={inputHandler}
          onChange={props.customerInfo(formState)}
        />
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CustomerInformationForm;
```

Custom hook:

```
import { useCallback, useReducer } from "react";

const formReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INPUT_CHANGE":
      let formIsValid = true;
      for (const inputId in state.inputs) {
        if (!state.inputs[inputId]) {
          continue;
        }
        if (inputId === action.inputId) {
          formIsValid = formIsValid && action.isValid;
        } else {
          formIsValid = formIsValid && state.inputs[inputId].isValid;
        }
      }
      return {
        ...state,
        inputs: {
          ...state.inputs,
          [action.inputId]: { value: action.value, isValid: action.isValid },
        },
        isValid: formIsValid,
      };
    case "SET_DATA":
      return {
        inputs: action.inputs,
        isValid: action.formIsValid,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const useForm = (initialInputs, initialValidity) => {
  const [formState, dispatch] = useReducer(formReducer, {
    inputs: initialInputs,
    isValid: initialValidity,
  });

  const inputHandler = useCallback((id, value, isValid) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "INPUT_CHANGE",
      value: value,
      isValid: isValid,
      inputId: id,
    });
  }, []);

  const setFormData = useCallback((inputData, formValidity) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "SET_DATA",
      inputs: inputData,
      formIsValid: formValidity,
    });
  }, []);

 
  return [formState, inputHandler, setFormData,];
};
```

Any solutions as to what I could do to get the form to re render empty??

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use the setFormData method returned by your hook (you have omitted it in your `CustomerInformationForm` component).

Then you can call it in the form, when some condition is met in an effect:

```
const initialState = useRef({
    name: {
      value: "",
      isValid: false,
    },
    phone: {
      value: "",
      isValid: false,
    },
    address: {
      value: "",
      isValid: true,
    },
  });

let [formState, inputHandler, setFormData] = useForm(
    initialState,
    initialValidity
);

 useEffect(() => {
    console.log("customerinfo refreshing");
    setTriggerRefresh(props.refresh);
    setFormData(initialState.current);
 }, [props.refresh]);
```

You can also store the `initialState` value with `useRef`, to avoid re-running the effect unnecessarily.

Comment: This still does not change all the inputs on my form to be empty. Could there be something wrong with the functionality of my custom hook?

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a small example in codesandbox?